# Flutter Scroll Carousel above listview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to add carousel above in listview.builder but the scrolling only happens below in carousel, and the carousel is fixed

// scroll carousel here

```
new Expanded(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                         return itemFeed(context: context, index: index);
                    }
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Column` to achieve this. Remember to wrap the `ListView.builder` with a `Expanded` widget inside the `Column`.

Example -

```
Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Text('Fixed Box'),
          color: Colors.pink,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("Index - " + index.toString()),
            itemCount: 100,
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```